# After extracting an AppImage and making some changes how to build the AppImage again?

Tags: packaging, appimage

I have downloaded a software as an AppImage then I have extracted it as follows:

```
./softwareName.AppImage --appimage-extract

# The result is a directory: squashfs-root
```

I have made some changes to the settings in that extracted directory `squashfs-root`.

**My question** is: How to build the AppImage from the directory `squashfs-root`

I appreciate your help

P.S: I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3

Answer (score 3):

I think I have found the answer. By downloading `appimagetool` from the [github page](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/releases) (which is an AppImage itself) and running it as follows:

```
./appimagetool-x86_64.AppImage  ./squashfs-root
```

This build the AppImage.